# How do I recover cleanly from this "no branch" scenario

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

As a result of my experimenting with switching between two commits, I have ended up in a situation where GitExtensions reports `(no branch)` for my repository.  Here's the output from `git reflog`:

[image]

I haven't use branches, or intentionally anyway. My last commit was `91d96ff`. I then started the experimenting.  I checked out the previous commit (`699415c`) and confirmed that the working set had reverted to the files as they were at that commit (except for the datestamps - I can't get used to that!).  I then checked out `91d96ff` again and then bounced a couple of times between these two commits, the last checkout leaving the head at `91d96ff`, where it was when I started.  I have made changes to the sources since the last commit.

Here's how GitExtensions shows it:

[image]

And I notice that the little red triangle that is normally next to the `Master` is missing - I assume that indicates where the head is (or isn't in this case).  I presume I have a detached head?

Why is Git reporting this "no branch"?  What is the clean and proper way to recover from this? Is GitExtension's `Reset current branch to here` all I need?

I'm curious to know what I might have done to end up in this state.

Comment: Run `git checkout master`. Since `91d96ff` is the same commit, it shouldn't change your working directory at all.

Comment: Thanks @Rob.  Won't that overwrite the uncommitted changes I have made since then?

Comment: No, uncommitted changes will be kept as is. If there is a conflict, you will be unable to checkout master - in which case you'll have to commit and merge/rebase

Comment: I took a deep breath and ...  all good. The GitExtensions dialog gave a `don't change` option which was pretty reassuring.

Comment: If you're ever unsure if git is going to obliterate your unchecked-in changes, you can always make a temporary commit to be safe :). But for the most part, unless you're using `--force`, it's unlikely you're going to blow away your changes

Comment: How is a temporary commit different (where does it commit to)?  I was just trying to commit when I originally ran into this "no branch" snag.

Comment: you can use `git stash` for temporary commits.  I wrote about it in my answer.

Comment: you can `git stash` multiple commits and view them using `git stash list` and `git stash show` / `git stash show stash@{0}` ... and so on...

Comment: @rossmcm When I said a temporary commit, I meant a normal commit that you were planning to rollback in the future (for example, `reset` to essentially put the changes back into your working set). However, as mkrufky mentioned, you can also use stash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably did the equivalent of checking out a commit, like so: `git checkout 91d96ff`  This will put you in a detached state, which is what your UI means when it reports "no branch".

The best thing to do to get back to "normal" would be to `git stash` your local changes, then `git checkout master` (or whatever branch you were originally working with) Then `git stash pop` to restore the local changes that you may have had.  If there are any conflicts, they will be presented to you at that point.

This was caused by the fact that you were "checking out" different commits.

Comment: Wasn't from me;-).  Thanks for your answer.  I've outlines the steps that got me into trouble in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would detail the steps that gave rise for the OP.  I have been using GitExtensions for all my Git-related stuff.

Originally, my repo status looked like below and I was experimenting with checking out earlier commits, so I right-click and choose `Checkout revision`:

- [image]

After that, the appearance was:

- [image]

Note the `(no branch)` displayed, and the fact that the `master` node is grayed out. Having confirmed that what happened to the working set was what I hoped would happen, I then reverted back to the original state with:

- [image]

Which got me back to the original working set presumably, but still with `no branch`.  What I should have done was:

- [image]